# Select from sub list only with children()

Tags: jquery

The HTML:

```
<ul class="main_list">
    <li class="list_folder">One</li>
    <li class="list_folder">Two</li>
    <li class="list_folder">New list <ul class="hide_list">
            <li class="list_folder">New one</li>
            <li class="list_folder">New Two</li>
            <li class="list_folder">Third list<ul class="hide_list">
                    <li class="list_folder">Third one</li>
                    <li class="list_folder">Third two</li>
                </ul></li>
        </ul></li>
</ul>
```

What I want to do: All sub lists with class of "hide_list" are hidden with CSS. When I click on li that contains the hidden list, I would like that hidden list to toggle open/close.
My jquery code:

```
$('.list_folder').on('click',function(){
    $(this).children('.hide_list').slideToggle();
}
```

The issue: it works on first sub list, but when I click on next sublist deeper it will select the next deeper list and also the outer lists, and in result the whole list will collapse.

What am i doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.list_folder').on('click',function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $(this).find('.hide_list:first').slideToggle();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2GLA5/8/)**

#### Note

You don't need to use `.children()`, `.find()` will accomplish your job.

> .stopImmediatePropagation() keeps the rest of the handlers from being
> executed and prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.

Read more about **[.stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/)**

Comment: Thanks for fast response, your suggestion works, however i would like to toggle the list that was clicked on, i wouldnt want to expand all the sublists, that is whats happening with your code.

Comment: By adding e.stopImmediatePropagation() it works. I am new to jquery, my question: what would be the best way to achieve this independent toggle effect for selected ul? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

your function is right. you have to add one more line `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`.

```
$('.list_folder').on('click',function(event){
  /* add one more line */
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  $(this).children('.hide_list').slideToggle();
}
```